# Plone 5 custom content types missing in portal navigation

Tags: dexterity, plone-5.x

When adding dexterity content types to my Plone 5.3 instance, they do not show up in the portal navigation.

I tried ttw and with a custom product.

The catalog is up-to-date. I forced rebuilding with no success.

The behaviors added to the type are:

```
<property name="behaviors">
  <element value="plone.dublincore"/>
  <element value="plone.namefromtitle"/>
  <element value="plone.allowdiscussion"/>
  <element value="plone.excludefromnavigation"/>
  <element value="plone.shortname"/>
  <element value="plone.constraintypes"/>
  <element value="plone.relateditems"/>
  <element value="plone.nextprevioustoggle"/>
 </property>
```

How can I make the custom types show up in the portal navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layer 8 error.

After fiddling around with other settings, I remembered that this is actually an option. Under `<PORTAL_URL>/@@navigation-controlpanel`, one can select the content types that appear in the portal navigation.